# Media from MemoryStream not displaying (or not playing)

Tags: c#, vlc, memorystream, libvlc, libvlcsharp

In a C# application I use LibVLC via NuGet packages.

I have created a MemoryStream and gave it to Media:

```
MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
bool playing = false;

public void dataArrived(byte[] d) {
  buffer.Write(d, 0, d.Length);
  if (!playing) {
    playing = true;
    mediaPlayer.Play(new Media(LibVLC, buffer));
  }
}
```

Now `dataArrived` is called when data is arrived from the network (this is a live stream).
Data is a valid mp4 stream (fragmented, plays nicely in HTML5 Video).

However VLC is not displaying it. In the log I see a lot of messages about prefetch:

```
prefetch stream debug: end of stream
```

VLC can read and dump the boxes, however there is a message (debug, not error!) which might be interesting:

```
mp4 demux debug: unrecognized major media specification (iso5).
```

Then there is another interesting batch of messages:

```
mp4 demux warning: cannot select track[Id 0x1]
main input debug: EOF reached
main decoder debug: killing decoder fourcc `h264'
main decoder debug: removing module "avcodec"
main demux debug: removing module "mp4"
mp4 demux debug: freeing all memory
main input debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
```

Is there some trick (config) for LibVLC to play fragmented mp4 on the fly (data is not available in advance)?

Or maybe `MemoryStream` is a wrong choice for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The MemoryStream is not a good fit for a live stream, because it signals the end of the stream, because it can't know that new data will be added later.

Use your own implementation of `Stream` or create your own `MediaInput`.

Be careful, you seem to use an older version of LibVLCSharp. The newer API does not use a Stream directly, but needs a MediaInput to work.

If you manage to make it work, would you like to submit a live stream sample at LibVLCSharp? This is a feature that we are asked about.

Comment: I want to remove the data that already have been read by VLC. Is it possible? If I write my own MediaInput I can exclude the seek function (or return false). I just don't want to have a continuously increasing buffer holding the whole stream from the beginning. Once I succeed I'll put it here, and I can submit it to LibVLCSharp too, yes.

Comment: One more detail: LibVLC calls int Read(IntPtr buf, uint len) when it needs new data. Is it okay if I return with 0 (if I don't yet have new data)? Will VLC try again, or I shall force it once I have new data?

Comment: 0 means EOF. As stated [here](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#gabeece3802e4b17a655e45c4ff4a2bbda), your implementation should wait for data to be available. As for your other question, If you can, I think it would be better to handle that with a [Pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipelines.pipe?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1). Feel free to come and chat on gitter if you need help to implement that.